# Does Handbrake on the Mac take advantage of OpenCL on a video card?

Tags: macos, encoding, opencl

I recently upgraded my GPU to one that supports double precision floating point math and apparently is compliant with OpenCL 1.2. While I presume that most applications won't see any difference, I am curious if Handbrake would?

Obviously video transcoding is a massively taxing operation on a computer. Seeing how GPUs are rather optimized for this duty, I'm curious if either Handbrake directly (coded it) or indirectly (OSX math library) utilizes OpenCL when available?

It would be nice to see if the GPU is able to make things faster automatically for the heavy lifting math tasks!

Comment: Handbrake actually uses a lot of [open source libraries](https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/blob/master/THANKS.markdown) - it would be these libraries that would take advante of OpenCL